# What 50s/60s movie had an astronaut who came back to earth as a pock-marked "radiation monster"

Tags: story-identification, astronauts

I remember seeing this movie in the early 1960's.  As I recall, an astronaut was launched into space, the spaceship was lost and he was presumed dead.  But he had actually gotten back to earth and had become a "radiation monster".

His head was oversized, spherical in shape and had pock-marks that looked like someone has taken an ice-cream scoop to the head. He killed people just by being near them since he was sending out radiation all the time.

That's about all I recall - aside from getting the bejeebers scared out of me.  I think I was about six at the time!

Answer (score 11):

It sounds a lot like "[Monster a Go-Go!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_a_Go-Go)", released in 1965 and often considered **one of the worst scifi films ever made**.

[image: Monster a Go-Go!]

[image: Monster a Go-Go! 2]

Answer (score 1):

When a kid I saw a film with that plot, [First Man Into Space](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0052805/).

It starred Marshall Thompson, who later played "Daktari" in TV show of that name. At the film's end Thompson asks the captured man/monster why he'd done what he did; the (dying?) monster replies

> *"I just had to be the first man in space!"*

Per IMDB

> Rivalry between brothers leads to main story line. Navy Commander
>   Chuck Prescott(Marshall Thompson)has developed the Y12 aircraft to
>   test how far man can go up in the atmosphere.
>
> His brother, Lt. Dan Prescott(Bill Edwards), seems to be the best test
>   pilot around and is chosen to go up in the Y12. Dan of course has a
>   problem with taking orders and is also an over confident daredevil.
>   On Dan's second flight, he hits over the 300 miles up comfort zone and
>   his craft passes through a meteor dust storm. Returning to earth, Dan
>   becomes a monster that resembles 200 pounds of bad asphalt. He also
>   has a demanding craving for blood, whether it be from farm animals or
>   fellow human beings.
>
> Short runtime of an hour and seventeen minutes; black & white with
>   near stoic acting...typical of low budget sci-fi.
>
> Rounding out the cast is Marla Landi, Robert Ayers and Carl Jaffe.
>   Noteworthy trivia: about two months after this film was released; the
>   Russians put the real first man in space.  Scary as hell